# json to nsmutablearray in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

We have json file (content.json).We need get data form .json file and then place into NSMutablearray. We tried like this

```
 NSString* path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"content" ofType:@"json"];

NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

 NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];

   id allKeys = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];
NSLog(@"Key ***  %@",allKeys);

    for (int i=0; i<[allKeys count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *arrayResult = [allKeys objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"name=%@",[arrayResult objectForKey:@"Description"]);

    }
```

`allKeys` Value is null

```
JsonString is


    [
          {
          "ID": “2”,
          "MessageType": "0",
          "Description": "Promotions”,
          "ExpiryDateTime": "2015-07-10 12:00:00", 
          "Html": "<div class=\"ad_box\"><img class=\"banner\" src=\"jewellery.jpg\"\/><h3>"Hot" Items<ul \/><\/div>"
          },
          {
          "ID": "4",
          "MessageType": "1",
          "Description": "Offers”,
          "ExpiryDateTime": "2015-07-09 2:00:00", 
          "Html": "<div class=\"ad_box\"><img class=\"banner\" src=\"Williams-Petersan.jpg\"\/><h3>"Hot" Items - 2<ul \/><\/div>"
           }
           {
           "ID": “6”,
          "MessageType": “2”,
          "Description": "Invitations”,
          "ExpiryDateTime": "2015-07-09 3:00:00", 
          "Html": "<div class=\"ad_box\"><img class=\"banner\" src=\"Puma.jpg\"\/><h3>"Hot" Items - 2<ul \/><\/div>"
           }
]
```

We need Description data placed into ArrayResult

Please guide to us

Comment: 'NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted' is only used for writing

Comment: What does `error` report???????

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.  (The readily-available error messages should be reported in your question.)

Comment: @Hot Licks Why not try to be a little more constructive? We all know how to copy/paste from a manual.

Comment: @turingtested - I was "constructive". There are error messages produced by NSJSONSerialization and they should be examined (and reported in the question). A question about that class is nowhere near complete until the contents of the error messages are reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your json is invalid - notice the unicode quotes around ID 2 or 6 - ID 4 is fine -- there multiple errors more which can easily be fixed :) e.g. by using some online son validator website / a supported editor

the code itself looks okay

**BUT**

it wont be a mutable array ;) it will be immutable. If you want Mutability, pass NSJSONReadingMutableContainers to the JSON

Answer (score 0):

You don't need go through making a `NSString` before `NSData`. Just use the class method `dataWithContentsOfFile:` instead. And to make the array mutable, just add the command `mutableCopy` when serializing it:

```
NSString* path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"content" ofType:@"json"];
NSData* jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
id allKeys = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"Key ***  %@", allKeys);

for (int i=0; i<[allKeys count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *arrayResult = [allKeys objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"name = %@",[arrayResult objectForKey:@"Description"]);
}
```

And here is correct json-data that will work with the code:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "MessageType": "0",
        "Description": "Promotions",
        "ExpiryDateTime": "2015-07-10 12:00:00",
        "Html": "<div class=\"ad_box\"><img class=\"banner\" src=\"jewellery.jpg\"\/><h3>\"Hot\" Items<ul \/><\/div>"
    },
    {
        "ID": "4",
        "MessageType": "1",
        "Description": "Offers",
        "ExpiryDateTime": "2015-07-09 2:00:00",
        "Html": "<div class=\"ad_box\"><img class=\"banner\" src=\"Williams-Petersan.jpg\"\/><h3>\"Hot\" Items - 2<ul \/><\/div>"
    },
    {
        "ID": "6",
        "MessageType": "2",
        "Description": "Invitations",
        "ExpiryDateTime": "2015-07-09 3:00:00",
        "Html": "<div class=\"ad_box\"><img class=\"banner\" src=\"Puma.jpg\"\/><h3>\"Hot\" Items - 2<ul \/><\/div>"
    },

]
```